# Desktop application using php

Tags: php

Is it possible make a desktop application using php?
There are many clients who don’t want to make there data online or few of them won’t be able to start xampp everytime and run the application.
Is there any other way possible which makes the work easy?
Or is there any hybrid way kind of thing?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: [PHP-GTK](https://gtk.php.net/)

Comment: There are also compiler solutions like [PHP2EXE](https://www.exeoutput.com/php-exe).

Comment: You can, but there are much richer, better supported and less troublesome ways to build a desktop app. PHP was designed for servers, really. Also be aware that since PHP isn't compiled, you'd have to be comfortable with all your customers having a copy of the source code on their machines.

Comment: thanks @Barmar  they are intersting projects

Comment: @Markus Zeller, it is so intersting